# Salesforce Java script join or reference queries

Tags: javascript, salesforce, soql

I am trying to select data from a couple objects at the same time using Javascript.

I want to select the LOB__C, risk_state__c FROM Opportunity and the Contact's firstname and lastname that is related to that Opportunity. I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks guys.

Comment: How is the contact related to the opportunity? Contact Roles, custom relationship?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I thought I had it related, but it wasn't.  What would be be best practice? Should I query through the Account object or add a reference to Opportunity. Contact(parent) -> Opportunity(child). Still not sure how to create the query. Thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to access a single Contact, you would need to add a reference field on the Opportunity to the Contact (using either a Lookup or Master-Detail relationship field).

From there, you can query like this:

```
Select LOB__c, risk_state__c, 
    Contact__c, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName From Opportunity
```

If you're looking at accessing all/multiple contacts for an Opportunity, store them in the `OpportunityContactRole` object and use a query like this:

```
Select LOB__c, risk_state__c,
    (Select ContactId, 
        FirstName, LastName From OpportunityContactRoles) From Opportunity
```